# How do you teleport characters in Roblox without leaving residue?

Tags: roblox

How do you teleport characters in Roblox without causing the HumanoidRootPart to be out of sync with the character? I have found that moving just the HumanoidRootPart will cause the rest of the character to snap back in place where you want them to be, but to the server, it is still in place before the teleport. Is there a better method?

Comment: Could you give more context? There are certain scenarios where teleporting won't work. For example, moving another player's character from your own client.

Comment: @kojocrash All I gave was an example of teleporting a character, and moving characters should be done in the server.

Comment: @kojocrash It's a feature of stack overflow's, and is used to spread knowledge. The reason I used it is that I found that `model:MoveTo()` looks better to the server and can be used with all models.

Comment: ah okay. one thing to note about ``model:MoveTo(pos)`` is that if there's an object obstructing at the target position, the model will teleport to a position above the object. However, ``model:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(cf)`` will not reflect this behavior. It all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `model:MoveTo()` to move models (characters are models).

For example, a simple teleporter:

```
local debounce = false

-- the teleporter is just a part with the script it's child
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function (hit)

    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    
    if player and not debounce then
        debounce = true
        
        local char = player.Character
        local rootPart = char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        
        char:MoveTo(rootPart.Position + Vector3.new(0, 10, 0))
        
        wait(.5)
        debounce = false
    end
end)
```